# Cut .00 from float variable

Tags: php, format

I wrote this function for cutting two last characters from (float) type variable. I would like that e.g `315.00` becomes `315`

```
function formatFloat($value) {
    $integer = number_format($value, 2);
    return $integer;
}
```

But i have failed - function returns `315.00` :D What's wrong guys?

Comment: What about using `intval()`? Then you don't have to create your own `formatFloat()` function, just use the native PHP `intval()`.  If you want to use `number_format()` to remove decimals, the second argument needs to be zero, `number_format($value, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `intval` function. [Here is the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) for that.

Write you code like this:

```
function formatFloat($value) {

    $integer = intval($value);
    return $integer;

}
```

Or you can directly pass the variable in that:

```
intval($value);
```

Then you don't need to make the function.

Comment: I used solution from comment but your way also works - i gave you plus

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in the comments, if you just use `intval()`, you can get the integer part of it, and effectively remove the decimal. This means that you don't need a function `formatFloat()` at all, unless you intend on doing anything more inside it.

```
echo intval(315.00); // 315
```

If you insist on using `number_format()`, you should see that according to the documentation, the second parameter displays the amount of decimal places. You have set it to two, so you will get two decimal places. Set it to zero, or remove it altogether (as it's default zero).

```
echo number_format(315.00); // 315
echo number_format(315.00, 0); // 315
echo number_format(315.00, 2); // 315.00
```

- [Live demo](https://3v4l.org/kqgUj)
- [PHP.net on `number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)
- [PHP.net on `intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)